# EF Code first - custom ICollection getter

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity framework and I'm still trying to understand how to handle it.
I bumped in to a strange problem. I'm trying to create a customer getter for a "one->many" relationship but for some reason it is not working as I'm expecting.

Please take a look at the code below:

```
namespace DigitalCard.Data.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

    using DigitalCard.Data.Commons.Interfaces;
    using DigitalCard.Data.Commons;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public class User : BasicDbEntry, IUser, IBasicUser
    {
        public User(string userName, string firstName, string lastName) : this(userName)
        {
            this.UserName = userName;
            this.FirstName = firstName;
            this.LastName = lastName;
        }

        public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }

        //---> Table Attributes
        [Required]
        [Index("UserName", 1, IsUnique = true)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        //---> Referances to other tables
        public virtual ICollection<Phone> _phones { get;  set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones
        {
            get { return this._phones == null ? new List<Phone>() : this._phones.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).ToList<Phone>(); }
            set { this._phones = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Phone class:

```
public class Phone : BasicContact
{
    public Phone() : base() { }

    // Table Attributes
    [Required]
    [IsPhoneNumber]
    public string Number { get; set; }

}


public class BasicContact : BasicDbEntry
{

    public BasicContact()
    {
    }

    // Table Attributes
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Every type of contact should have a Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    // Reference to other table
    public virtual User _user { get; private set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual User User
    {
        get { return this._user; }
        set { this._user = value; }
    }
}


public class BasicDbEntry : IBasicDbEntry
{
    public BasicDbEntry() 
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        this.CreatedOn = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        this.DeletedOn = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
        this.ModifiedOn = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1);
    }

    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Every database item should have an Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}
```

The whole point of this exercise is to somehow tell EF to pull only the phone numbers that are not delete e.t. "`isDelete == false`" when I write UserInstance.Phones

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is that you have lazy loading enabled on your Icollection<phone>. Get rid of _virtual_ on that property.

Comment: "not working as I'm expecting" - What do you expect and what is the outcome?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: This is not a good pattern for the EF. Navigation properties is actually a map of "foreign keys" into objects. Leave `Phones` property simple, and use condition in the LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1):

this code below looks like you are going to dodge the EF.

```
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> _phones { get;  set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones
    {
        get { return this._phones == null ? new List<Phone>() : this._phones.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false).ToList<Phone>(); }
        set { this._phones = value; }
    }
```

I'd propose you to leave and modify only this line (as it should be done, by default of EF)

```
    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get;  set; }
```

And later in your  code, when you instantiate DbContext, just add this check for `IsDeleted`. That is not so big problem for performance, if you worry about that. DbContext anyway will have full copy of DbSets in memory in first cache level (told approximetely).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I've been doing this in this way exactly, but when I use those object in the logic I'm not directly accessing the db context. and so I still get all entries even the isDeleted ones

Comment: just get rid on "object directly accessing the db context" and make wrapper call for `isDeleted`